# Unable to use the generate_plugin.js script in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-6

I tried to run the plugin generator included in Kibana 7.0.0-alpha, but generate_plugin.js script doesn't exist after upgrading Kibana by running the .deb installation file for Kibana 7.0.0-alpha. I know I successfully installed Kibana 7.0.0-alpha because it runs properly through the browser. In addition, I attempted to run the script directly from clone of the git repo but I got a "Error: Cannot find module '@kbn/plugin-generator'" error. Do I have to manually define the generate_plugin script? I wasn't even able to find a scripts folder within my Kibana installation directory.